# How do I extract a string of text in c#

Tags: c#, string, split

i am having trouble splitting a string in c#
have a string **(text in textbox0)**

```
start and dffdfdddddddfd<m>one</m><m>two</m><m>three</m><m>four</m>dbfjnbjvbnvbnjvbnv and end
```

and I want to extract the text between `<m>` and `</m>` when click in button1 and i need **3 output :**

**output 1** :
one two three four **(output to textbox1)**

**output 2** :
four **(output to textbox2)**

**output 3** :
one **(output to textbox3)**

what do i do ?

how would I do this?

please give me full code for button1_Click

thanks and regards.

Comment: The entire input wouldn't happen to be valid xml would it?

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-split

Comment: use a regex, unless you are trying to parse HTML or XML

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try a regular expression to capture the four values in a list, either using LINQ:

```
List<string> results = Regex.Matches(s, "<m>(.*?)</m>")
                            .Cast<Match>()
                            .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                            .ToList();
```

Or for C# 2.0:

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(s, "<m>(.*?)</m>"))
{
     results.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

You can then use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx), [`Enumerable.First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx) (or `results[0]`) and [`Enumerable.Last`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb358775.aspx) (or `results[results.Length - 1]`) to get the outputs you need.

If this is XML you should use an XML parser instead.

Comment: can u send 1 sample proje for me ?

Comment: Judging from your update, it seems you should use an XML parser instead. Can you post a little more information about the structure of the document?

Answer (score 1):

With customary warning against using Regex for XML and HTML:

You can extract text between `<m>` and `</m>` like so:

```
     string input =
            "start and dffdfdddddddfd<m>one</m><m>two</m><m>three</m><m>four</m>dbfjnbjvbnvbnjvbnv and end";
     var matches = Regex.Matches(input, "<m>(.*?)</m>");
     foreach (Match match in matches)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Program{
    static void Main(string[] args){
        string data = "start and dffdfdddddddfd<m>one</m><m>two</m><m>three</m><m>four</m>dbfjnbjvbnvbnjvbnv and end";
        string xmlString = "<root>" + data + "</root>";
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
        var ie = doc.Descendants("m");
        Console.Write("output1:");
        foreach(var el in ie){
            Console.Write(el.Value + " ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("\noutput2:{0}",ie.Last().Value);
        Console.WriteLine("output3:{0}",ie.First().Value);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot but how can output to textbox1 , textbox2 , textbox3 ?

Comment: textBox1.Text = "Output String"