# extract the text between two tag in C#

Tags: c#

i am having trouble splitting in c#

**(text in textbox0)**

```
start and dffdfdddddddfd<m>one</m><m>two</m><m>three</m><m>four</m>dbfjnbjvbnvbnjvbnv and end
```

and I want to extract the text between `<m>` and `</m>` when click in button1 and i need

**output 1** :
one two three four **(output to textbox1)**

**output 2** :
four **(output to textbox2)**

**output 3** :
one **(output to textbox3)**

what do i do ?

how would I do this?

please give me **full code for button1_Click** please.i am amateur in C# , so i need for out put code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the codez

```
var items = new List<string>();
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(text, "<m>(.*?)</m>"))
    items.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);
string output = String.Join(" ", items);

someTextBox.Text =  output;

if (items.Any())
   anotherTextBox.Text = items[0];

if (items.Count > 2)
   whateverTextBox.Text = items[3];
```

Comment: I think he wants to know how to plug those values into his textboxes. He's asked the exact same [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7701745/how-do-i-extract-a-string-of-text-in-c) before.

Comment: Thanks but i need Code for output1 , 2 , 3 i am very very very amateur but only need for this code . thanks

Comment: @Mehrdad: Can you post what you have done so far? This will make it easier for people to help. Especially since we don't know how you named your textboxes.

Comment: @Hasan Khan  & Ilian Pinzon : Thanks for ur help

Comment: @Mehrdad: No worries. Please accept the answer that helped you the most by clicking its check mark. This way, people will be more willing to help.

Answer (score 4):

Rather the writing code for you, I'd like to point you at Regular Expressions. Take a look at [Using regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html). This is one way you can parse the text to find the bits you want. In particular, read up on "groups".

Once you've got the matching working, you can extract the match groups and parse the text into the fields you need.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks a lot , but you can't give me code ? please give me code for this sample King Regards.

Comment: No :) I've given you the "idea", time to go and learn something!

Answer (score 4):

use

```
 Regex.Matches(TextString, "<m>(.*?)</m>")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try RegEx like this :

```
string source = "start and dffdfdddddddfd<m>one</m><m>two</m><m>three</m><m>four</m>dbfjnbjvbnvbnjvbnv and end";
List<string> destList = new List<string>();

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(source, "<m>(.*?)</m>"))
    destList.Add(match.Groups[1].Value);

textbox1.Text = String.Join(" ", destList); 
textbox2.Text = destList[3];
.....
```